# Why is this pure virtual method not compiling?

Tags: c++, pure-virtual

I use a **pure virtual** method as shown in the code below.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Advertisment
{
public:
   vitual void price (int Uchrg, int no_of_unt) = 0;
   {
   }
};

class TVadvertisment : public Advertisment
{
public:
   void price (int Uchrg, int no_of_unt)
   {
      int adPrice = Uchrg * no_of_unt;
      cout << "Advertisment Price: " << adPrice;
   }
};

int main()
{
   TVadvertisment T;
   T.price(1000, 60);
   return 0;
}
```

As I know a pure virtual function will be declared as `virtual void display() = 0;`. But the *Code::Blocks* compiler show an error because of this `= 0`. Without that it will compile successfully.

And also I didn't use pointers to call methods of derived class.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] *in the question itself*.

Comment: _I use Pure Virtual as below._ What below? **Copy-paste** all the relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: Please don't link images of text, just copy and paste the relevant information into your question.

Comment: A pure virtual does not have the { and } after it...

Comment: Also, please don't try to guess how the C++ syntax works, that won't work.

Comment: The error is on the line with the `{`, and the message even mentions that. Get rid of the braces. Pure virtual functions have no body.

Comment: is that must use pointers in main function to call methods of derived class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is pure virtual, which means the method is virtual and not even implemented in the base class `(= 0)`.
So you have to delete the block after it.

It has to be:

```
virtual price(int Uchrg, int no_of_unt) = 0;
```

without the `{ }`.

Virtual means, that classes that inherit from a base class can override the method and called via the base class interface. If a class has a pure virtual method, the class is abstract and this function needs to be overridden by classes that inherit from that base class to be instantiated.

In short:

**Virtual:**

```
virtual price(int Uchrg, int no_of_unt)
{
   // Implementation
}
```

Has an implementation is the base class. Sub classes does **not** need to override, but they can. The class is not abstract and can be instanciated.

**Pure virtual:**

```
virtual price(int Uchrg, int no_of_unt) = 0; // No implementation
```

There is no implementation, the sub classes must override this to be not abstract.

**Call a virtual method via base class:**

```
Base* pBase = new Derived;
pBase->fun();
```

The method is called via the interface of the base class, but it will be the derived class' method.